# wget - work with arguments

Tags: sed, arguments, wget

I have a list of URI: uri.txt with

```
category1/image1.jpeg
category1/image32.jpeg
category2/image1.jpeg
```

and so on, and need to download them from domain example.com with wget, with additional changing filename (final at save) to categoryX-imageY.jpeg

I understand, that I should read uri.txt line by line, add "http://example.com/" in front of each line and change "/" to "-" in each line.

What I have now:

1. Reading from uri.txt [work]
2. Adding domain name in front of each URI [work]
3. Change filename to save [fail]

I'm trying to do this with:

```
wget 'http://www.example.com/{}' -O '`sed "s/\//-/" {}`' < uri.txt
```

but wget fails (it depends what type of quotation sign I'm using: ` or ') with:

```
wget: option requires an argument -- 'O'
```

or

```
sed `s/\//-/` category1/image1.jpeg: No such file or directory
sed `s/\//-/` category1/image32.jpeg: No such file or directory
```

Could you tell, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do that:

```
while read LINE ; do
  wget "http://example.com/$LINE" -O $(echo $LINE|sed 's=/=-=')
done < uri.txt
```

In other words, read `uri.txt` line by line (the text being placed in `$LINE` bash variable), before performing the `wget` and saving with modified name (I use another `sed` delimitor, to avoid escaping `/` and making it more readable)

Answer (score 0):

When I want to construct a list of args to be executed, I like to use xargs:

```
 cat uri.txt | sed "s#\(.*\)/\(.*\)#http://example.com/\1/\2 -O \1-\2#" | xargs -I {} wget {}
```

Comment: Can you provide some context to your answer, that way future readers can learn how to apply it to their issues and not just in this situation.